# Query para retornar apenas os valores mais altos

Tags: mysql, query

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

> Contrato  |  Codigo  |  Ano
>   13               7800        2015
>   12               7800        2014
>   12               7800        2013
>   12               7801        2016
>   12               7801        2013
>   12               5102        2017

Estou tentando fazer uma query para retornar o resultado abaixo, ou seja, o maior "ano" para cada combinação de "codigo" e "contrato", porém informando apenas o número do contrato. Caso quisesse filtrar a tabela para o contrato "12", o resultado teria que ser:

> Contrato  |  Codigo  |  Ano
>   12               7800        2014
>   12               7801        2016
>   12               5102        2017

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes do que gostaria? Não ficou muito claro.

Comment: @Marconi, alterei a pergunta. Estava confusa, agora penso que comparando os dois exemplos fica mais fácil.

Comment: @Dherik editei a pergunta, penso que agora ficou mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você devia ter mencionado qual a query utilizada, mas tente:

```
SELECT contrato, MAX(ano) AS 'max_ano' FROM c GROUP BY contrato;
```

ou:

```
SELECT contrato, MAX(ano) AS 'max_ano' FROM c GROUP BY contrato ORDER BY max_ano DESC LIMIT 1;
```

---

Banco criado com:

```
CREATE TABLE "c" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    "contrato" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "codigo" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "ano" INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(1,13,7800,2015);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(2,12,7800,2014);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(3,12,7800,2013);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(4,12,7801,2016);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(5,12,7801,2013);
INSERT INTO "c" VALUES(6,12,5102,2017);
```

---

Alguns testes:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM c;
1|13|7800|2015
2|12|7800|2014
3|12|7800|2013
4|12|7801|2016
5|12|7801|2013
6|12|5102|2017
sqlite> SELECT contrato, MAX(ano) AS 'max_ano' FROM c GROUP BY contrato;
12|2017
13|2015
sqlite> SELECT contrato, MAX(ano) AS 'max_ano' FROM c GROUP BY contrato ORDER BY max_ano DESC LIMIT 1;
12|2017
sqlite>
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta, penso que agora ficou mais claro o pretendido. Entretanto a pergunta é sobre como fazer a query, logo não tenho uma, mas obrigado pela tentativa.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Esta resposta está correta, para obter o resultado que deseja simplesmente acrescente o campo código no `group by` (além do filtro, é claro): `SELECT contrato, codigo, MAX(ano) AS 'max_ano' FROM c WHERE contrato = 12 GROUP BY contrato, codigo;`

Comment: @mgibsonbr tens razão!

Comment: Apenas adicionei o campo "codigo" (além do filtro) e resolveu o problema.

Answer (score -1):

Não esta claro o que você quer, então vou cobrir os dois jeitos que entendi sua pergunta.

Para obter o maior ano de acordo com o código do contrato específico, utilize:

`SELECT * FROM Tabela WHERE Contrato = 12 ORDER BY Ano DESC LIMIT 1`

Se quiser o contrato com o maior ano, utilize:

`SELECT * FROM Tabela ORDER BY Ano DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Editei a pergunta, penso que agora ficou mais claro o pretendido.